# Base de Datos y SpiderCrawl

Tags: python, scrapy

Tengo una base de datos en Stata (Sé que es complicado usar Stata y Python, pero no hay problema pues puedo exportar la base de datos a Excel)

Ahora bien, esta base de datos tiene Nombre, Apellido, Fecha de nacimiento como variables, y quiero usar los datos de esta base para hacer webscrapping.

La url tiene un campo de Nombre, Apellido, Fecha de nacimiento y un boton de consultar.

[image]

De ahi que busco que para la base de datos, previamente mencionada se realice este proceso.

Al poner la informacion anterior, la pagina genera una pestaña con informacion que deseo recabar.

¿Es posible realizar esto con Python y ScrapySpider?

Comment: Cuál es la URL de la que se va a obtener la información? Se debe conocer la estructura y si los datos se devuelven en JSON, HTML u otro formato.

Comment: si es posible. Una alternativa es que compartas la URL, u otra es que compartas todos los requests relacionados para poder emularlos con scrapy.